# Upper Triangular Matrices is a lie group

Tags: matrices, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds

I'm trying to prove that this is a lie group and compute its tangent space at the identity. I would try to show its a closed subgroup of $GL(n)$ by showing its the preimage of a closed set under a continuous map on $GL(n)$, but doing it this way doesn't help compute the tangent space at the identity (I'm also struggling to actually find such a map). Any suggestions?

Comment: To show that the set it is a Lie subgroup, you don't need to compute the tangent space at the identity.

Comment: sorry, I want to show it is a lie group and compute the tangent space. I just edited my question.

Comment: See the solution [here](https://books.google.at/books?id=UdI7DQAAQBAJ&pg=PA121&lpg=PA121&dq=show+that+the+upper+triangular+matrices+form+a+Lie+group&source=bl&ots=dniNf4yiD0&sig=rMvTVTe52__fpNLYicxU-sxzRaM&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjExuj2xebVAhWBaRQKHUKtDaE4ChDoAQgtMAE#v=onepage&q=show%20that%20the%20upper%20triangular%20matrices%20form%20a%20Lie%20group&f=false), Problem 74.

Answer (score 5):

I believe you talking about the invertible upper triangular matrices $IUT(n)$. To show that its is a Lie group, you can to show it is closed in $Gl(n)$, it is defined by $a_{ij}=0, i>j$. So it is closed.

Let $UT(n)$ be the space of upper triangular matrices, it is a vector spaces and $IUT(n)$ is an open subspace of $UT(n)$, this vector space induces on $IUT(n)$ a structure of a manifold such that the multiplication, the inverse map are continuous for the topology, so it is a structure of Lie group and the tangent space at any point is just $UT(n)$.

Comment: why does $a_{ij}=0$ for $i>j$ mean $IUT(n)$ is closed in $GL(n)$ ?

Comment: @AlexandarSolženjicin We identify $GL(n)$ with $R^{n^2}$. Consider $IUT(n)$ is the zero set of the function $f: GL(n) \rightarrow R^{n(n-1)/2}$ defined by the projection onto entries $a_{ij}$ such that $i > j$. So $IUT(n)$ is exactly $f^{-1}(0)$, but $\{0\}$ is closed in $R^{n(n-1)/2}$, hence $IUT(n)$ is closed by continuity of projection.